# Why doesn't line-height work on my input / form element?

Tags: html, css

I have a row of elements, every other element will accept a line-height, except the search, which is a `<form class="">` with inputs and an absolute position search button.

Here's how it should look:
[image: The search is properly aligned.]

vs. how it actually looks (no line-height, item stuck to top):

[image: The search is glued to the top, no space.]

I've tried several things such as displaying in-line and removing Chrome's default `-webkit` stylings that were applied, but none seemed to have worked.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/header/style-header_1.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- External CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="socicon/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400i" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="header-social-icons-list col-sm-4">
                    <ul id="social-icons-header">
                        <li id="facebook"><a href="www.facebook.com"><i class="socicon-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li id="googleplus"><a href="www.plus.google.com"><i class="socicon-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li id="twitter"><a href="www.twitter.com"><i class="socicon-googleplus"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="header-logo col-sm-4">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo"><a href="www.google.com"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="header-search-box col-sm-4">
                    <form class="header-search" method="get" action="post.php">
                        <input name="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control"/>
                        <input name="search-button" type="button" value="Search" class="button-control"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="menu col-sm-12">
                <li class="menu-item-1"><a href="http://www.google.com/">Home</a>
                    <ul class="menu-dropdown">
                        <li class="menu-dropdown-item-1"><a href="http://www.google.com/">SubOne</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-dropdown-item-2"><a href="http://www.google.com/">Sub Two</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-dropdown-item-3"><a href="http://www.google.com/">Sub Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item-2"><a href="http://www.google.com/">Features</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item-3"><a href="http://www.google.com/">Recipes</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item-4"><a href="http://www.google.com/">About</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item-5"><a href="http://www.google.com/">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
/* Global Line-height */

.header .header-social-icons-list,
.header .header-search-box,
.header .header-logo {
    line-height: 130px;
}


.header .header-social-icons-list a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header .header-social-icons-list li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header .header-social-icons-list ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.header .header-logo img {
    max-height: 110px;
}

.header .menu {
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 24px !important;
}

.header .menu > li {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin: 0 12px 0 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header .menu li a {
    color: #525252;
}

.header .menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777777;
}


/* Dropdown */

.header .menu .menu-dropdown {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.1s;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 130px -46px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 130px -46px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 130px -46px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.header .menu li:hover .menu-dropdown {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
}

.header .menu .menu-dropdown li {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.header .menu .menu-dropdown li:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.header .menu .menu-dropdown li a {
}

.header .header-search {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.header .header-search .form-control {
    padding: 0 45px 0 20px;
}

.header .header-search .form-control {
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 240px;
    height: 48px;
}

.header .header-search .form-control:focus {
    border: 2px solid #dcdcdc;
}

.header .header-search .button-control {
    text-indent: -99999px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right: 24px;
    border: none;
    background: url('../../svg/search.svg') 0 0 no-repeat;
}


/* Responsive */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .header .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .header .header-social-icons-list,
    .header .header-search,
    .header .header-menu-bottom {
        display: none;
    }

    .header .header-logo {
        padding: 48px 0 48px 48px;
    }

    .header .header-logo img {
        max-width:100%;
        image-rendering: auto;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 468px) {

    .header .header-logo {
        bottom: 60px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {

    .header .header-search .form-control {
        width: 120px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Line height does not apply to text inputs for some reason.  But it looks like you want to just push it down, not change the line height of the text in the input.  Did you try a top-margin?

Comment: Margin works, yes, but, unfortunately, I'd like to use line-height for consistency, my builder allows me to drag a container's line-height to make things smaller / bigger based on the user's mouse movements.

Comment: You can't use line-height for input elements, because it will only apply to the text node in within and not the height of the input element itself. You should explore alternative strategies to vertically align your input: (1) use `top: 50%` and `margin-top: -(...)px` or `translateY(-50%)`, (2) use flexbox, (3) use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: center`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `line-height` doesn't work for `<input>`. **Period.**

Your best bet, as far as I can tell is to use `margin / padding` for spacing, alternatively, if all your elements in a line have a specific line-height:

```
.element-one,
.element-two,
.my-input-element {
/* .my-input-element won't get this, since it's an input */
    line-height: 130px;
}
```

Consider doing the following:

```
.my-input-element .class-for-the-text-form-itself {
    padding: 24px 30px 24px 20px;
}
```

This will make the "Search" text look as you'd expect, justified to left with a lot of space to the right.

Such, the form itself will take an equal ~60px (assuming text-size is 12px), leaving a nice, horizontally centered item that will look good with the other elements. Representative view:

[image: How this method would plan out.]

So the formula would be something like

`calculate_margins_for_search_element = ((line_height - (form_itself: padding-top + padding-bottom + inner-elem)) / 2)`, 
in our case, that results in

```
((130-(24+24+12)) / 2
```

resulting in a **padding / margin-top+bottom of 35px each.**

Obviously, depending on what's inside that `<input>`, you can either get the precise numbers for the margins or an approximation, play by eye when necessary.

Unfortunately, I believe this can yield some issues on responsive and when there's dynamic content, but some `@media-query` together with some `text-limiters and max-height/width` should take care of the issue.